# Datediff between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have those two tables

1-Add to queue table

```
TransID , ADD date 
10 , 10/10/2012
11 , 14/10/2012
11 , 18/11/2012
11 , 25/12/2012
12 , 1/1/2013
```

2-Removed from queue table

```
TransID , Removed Date 
10 , 15/1/2013
11 , 12/12/2012
11 , 13/1/2013
11 , 20/1/2013
```

The TansID is the key between the two tables , and I can't modify those tables, what I want is to query the amount of time each transaction spent in the  queue

It's easy when there is one item in each table , but when the item get queued more than once how do I calculate that?

Comment: I don't think your data model will support such a query. There would be no way to tell which ADD went with which REMOVE.

Comment: In example above, what should the result of this query be?

Comment: it should eventually get me something like this

TransID   , Total Queue Time 
10        , 65
11        , 79     -- in this case it should get the DATE diff between all rows and sum them

Comment: I agree with paul the data module dont support it i have been puling my hair for 4 hours now trying to find a way

Comment: Do they always get removed in the order they were added?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order TransIDs are entered into the Add table is the same order they are removed, you can use the following:

```
WITH OrderedAdds AS
(   SELECT  TransID,
            AddDate,
            [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TransID ORDER BY AddDate)
    FROM    AddTable
), OrderedRemoves AS
(   SELECT  TransID,
            RemovedDate,
            [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TransID ORDER BY RemovedDate)
    FROM    RemoveTable
)
SELECT  OrderedAdds.TransID,
        OrderedAdds.AddDate,
        OrderedRemoves.RemovedDate,
        [DaysInQueue] = DATEDIFF(DAY, OrderedAdds.AddDate, ISNULL(OrderedRemoves.RemovedDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
FROM    OrderedAdds
        LEFT JOIN OrderedRemoves
            ON OrderedAdds.TransID = OrderedRemoves.TransID
            AND OrderedAdds.RowNumber = OrderedRemoves.RowNumber;
```

The key part is that each record gets a rownumber based on the transaction id and the date it was entered, you can then join on both rownumber and transID to stop any cross joining.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1f72/5)**

Answer (score 0):

Answer 2: after your comments. (As a side note, some of your dates `15/1/2013`,`13/1/2013` do not represent proper date formats )

```
select transId, sum(numberOfDays) totalQueueTime
from (
    select a.transId,
       datediff(day,a.addDate,isnull(r.removeDate,a.addDate)) numberOfDays
    from AddTable a left join RemoveTable r on a.transId = r.transId
    order by a.transId, a.addDate, r.removeDate
) X
group by transId
```

Answer 1: before your comments

Assuming that there won't be a new record added unless it is being removed. Also note following query will bring `numberOfDays as zero for unremoved records`;

```
select a.transId, a.addDate, r.removeDate,
       datediff(day,a.addDate,isnull(r.removeDate,a.addDate)) numberOfDays
from AddTable a left join RemoveTable r on a.transId = r.transId
order by a.transId, a.addDate, r.removeDate
```

Comment: the second query got the diff between the first time of entrance and the last time of entrance , that's not exactly what we wanted because between the queue time there might be work times that must be deducted

Comment: I wasn't sure about that as OP had no such details. I have updated Answer2. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: There is probably problem with this, but i hope to send you in one possible direction. Make sure to expect problems.

You can try in the following direction (which might work in some way depending on your system, version, etc) :

```
SELECT transId, (sum(add_date_sum) - sum(remove_date_sum)) / (1000*60*60*24)
FROM
(
    SELECT transId, (SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(add_date)) as add_date_sum, 0 as remove_date_sum
    FROM add_to_queue 
    GROUP BY transId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT transId, 0 as add_date_sum, (SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(remove_date)) as remove_date_sum
    FROM remove_from_queue 
    GROUP BY transId
)
GROUP BY transId;
```

A bit of explanation: as far as I know, you cannot sum dates, but you can convert them to some sort of timestamps. Check if UNIX_TIMESTAMPS works for you, or figure out something else. Then you can sum in each table, create union by conveniently leaving the other one as zeto and then subtracting the union query.

As for that devision in the end of first SELECT, UNIT_TIMESTAMP throws out miliseconds, you devide to get days - or whatever it is that you want.

This all said - I would probably solve this using a stored procedure or some client script. SQL is not a weapon for every battle. Making two separate queries can be much simpler.

Comment: It think it would work if i have MYSQL , but im working on MSSQL

Comment: Nice that you mentioned that now... There was only an SQL tag. Either way, UNION queries should work anywhere, so you can figure out the UNIX_TIMESTAMP similar function in MSSQL...